# ArrayList de objetos c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

Tengo un ArrayList de objetos de una clase pero no se como acceder a la informacion del ArrayList.

```
class Personas
{
    string nombres ="";
    string apellidos ="";

    public Personas(string nombres,string apellidos)
    {
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;

    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Personas personas;
      ArrayList lista;

      Personas personas = new Personas("BYRON","RAMIREZ");
      lista = new ArrayList();
      lista.Add(personas);

      MessageBox.Show(personas[0]["nombre"]);
}
```

Me marca error a la hora de mostrar la informacion.

Comment: [0] se usa para indicar el elemento en el ArrayList,en este caso lista. Agregue dos opciones que puedes realizar, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas mal y a tener en cuenta en tu código:

De la clase `Personas`

No es buena práctica nombrar en plurar una clase que no es una coleccion, lo mismo para los campos, además deben ser públicos o no podras acceder a ellos fuera de la clase. Modificala a algo asi:

```
class Persona
{
    public string nombre ="";
    public string apellido = "";

    public Persona(string nombre, string apellido)
    {
        this.nombre = nombres;
        this.apellido = apellidos;
    }
}
```

El ArrayList te da error porque al acceder al elemento 0 de su posicion te devuelve el objeto de esa posicion, es decir, un elemento Persona, para poder acceder correctamente al campo nombre que indicas debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
 Persona p = (Persona)lista[0];

 MessageBox.Show(p.nombre);
```

Comment: También sería bueno que los campos dentro de la clase comiencen con mayúscula.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es sobre escribir el método `ToString()` :

```
class Personas
{
    string nombres = "";
    string apellidos = "";

    public Personas(string nombres, string apellidos)
    {
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Persona: " + nombres + " " + apellidos;
    }

}
```

de esta forma podrías imprimir el valor del objeto:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Personas personas;
    ArrayList lista;

    personas = new Personas("BYRON", "RAMIREZ");
    lista = new ArrayList();
    lista.Add(personas);

    MessageBox.Show(lista[0].ToString());
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra opción es agregar los modificadores `public` a las propiedades de tu objeto:

```
class Personas
    {
       public string nombres = "";
        public string apellidos = "";

        public Personas(string nombres, string apellidos)
        {
            this.nombres = nombres;
            this.apellidos = apellidos;

        }

    }
```

De esta forma podrías leer las propiedades:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Personas personas;
        ArrayList lista;

        personas = new Personas("BYRON", "RAMIREZ");
        lista = new ArrayList();
        lista.Add(personas);

        Personas persona = (Personas)lista[0];
        MessageBox.Show("Persona: " + persona.nombres + " " + persona.apellidos);

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]